# Getting albums for a Facebook group using FQL

Tags: facebook-fql

I can get the photos added directly into a group using this FQL

```
SELECT pid,aid,owner,src_small,src_big,src_big_height,src_big_width,
link,caption,created,modified,object_id 
                    FROM photo 
                    WHERE pid IN (SELECT pid FROM photo_tag WHERE subject={0}
```

Subject is the group Id

I can also get the albums for a user using this FQL

```
SELECT id,owner,name,created,modified,description,
      location,size,link,type,object_id,cover_pid FROM album WHERE owner = {1}
```

What I cannot see is how to use FQL to get the Albums for a Group. Can this be done?

TIA

Pat Long

Comment: can you edit your question and add more tags? `facebook-fql` is not in the list of `featured question's Related Tags`. so less people can read it. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You means Group or Page?

Because for a Page, it's like a User. So something like this:

```
SELECT aid, owner, name, object_id FROM album WHERE owner=idPage
```

ex:

```
SELECT aid, owner, name, object_id FROM album WHERE owner='5879608657'
```

For a Group, I think this is impossible because a group has no albums (?).
For example, this one http://www.facebook.com/group.php?gid=7522527187&v=photos has only a lot of photos but these photos are not in an album.

Question is: Is a Group can have an album?

Comment: so how to get these photos? I can use `"SELECT pid FROM photo_tag WHERE subject=7522527187"` get all the picture id, but I cannot transfer them into picture url. use `"SELECT link FROM photo WHERE pid='2495714665744782068'"` and return empty `[]`.(with fully access token)

Comment: Yes I do mean a Group, not a Page. Groups can have Albums. They never used to be able to but Facebook added it to the UI on the main site. Rather than click on the Photos link for a Group, look for the "Add Photo / Video" from teher you should be able to add a photo.

Comment: @cj333: For a Group I really don't know. It's awkward that the pid returned by photo_tag doesn't match in the photo table.

Comment: @PatLong-MunkiiYebee: You're right the new groups (for example, create now) can have albums. Like this one: http://www.facebook.com/groups/141882475916101. But I can't figure out to get these photos/albums.. "SELECT aid, owner, src FROM photo WHERE album_object_id='141882475916101'" doesn't works. So I'm stuck sorry.